# How to connect an operating homepage to a json file using React and Typescript files?

Tags: java, mysql, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to connect my test data to my homepage to display the dummy data I have created. It is supposed to show on the homepage, but I am having quite a few issues trying to figure out how to link the two.

My GitHub where my code is located is https://github.com/Senior-Project-2/tsu-software-engineering-react.git . The file with the dummy data is "clientsDb" and the Homepage code is "Home.tsx" in the Views folder. Please any help is appreciated.

My main goal is to get my file "clientsDb" in the Data Constants folder to display on the homepage data, but I am having quite a few issues trying to figure it out. I have an individual page to try to connect it, but have not completely figured out how to connect the pages to link to one another, so I have been trying to use it in the "App.tsx" file to at least make sure my code is running correctly.

More assistance please... When I make the changes from the answer down below I am getting this error - "TS2307: Cannot find module '../DataConstants/clientsDb.json' or its corresponding type declarations.". I will leave a screenshot below. [Error Message Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMGSF.png)